# Adding a JComboBox to a JPanel

Tags: java

I am trying to add a Combobox to a jpanel. I want to add the items for the combobox from an arraylist but it's not working. Nothing shows up. The code I am writing here is not the whole thing, I have a JFrame and inside the JFrame after I click a button the JPanel supposed to open.

```
                     ArrayList<Integer> days;
                     days = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                     for (int i=1; i<=31; i++) { 
                        days.add(i);

                     }
                    JPanel res = new JPanel();
                    res.setBounds(20, 50, 300, 300);
                    JComboBox<ArrayList<Integer>> day = new JComboBox<ArrayList<Integer>>();                         
                   day.addItem(days);
                   day.addItem(days);
                    res.add(day);
                    jf.add(res);

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to a model, then to the combo box

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
   model.addElement(i);
}
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
```

Comment: Thanks. So, I tried both ways and now the problem is nothing shows up when I click the button. I even tried to add an empty combobox and that didn't work either.

Comment: Without seeing how the code is strung together, there's not much we can do to help.  What you might want to do is make the panel invisibile, add it to the frame, and then have the button set the visibility to true.  You might also nee to do an revalidate() and repaint() on the frame.

Answer (score -1):

Your combobox instanciation seems not good.

This might be better:

`List<Integer> days = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=1; i<=31; i++)
     days.add(i);
JComboBox day = new JComboBox( days );`

See examples there: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html